# How to integrate custom static code analysis rules with xamarin studio?

Tags: c#, jenkins-plugins, code-analysis, xamarin-studio, stylecop

I am trying to run code analysis in xamarin .I tried using the FxCop and styleCop analysers, but only the xml files were parsed successfully.I want to run code analysis on both (.xaml & xaml.cs) files.

Can anyone tell me how to run code analysis with custom rule set while building xamarin studio project in jenkins and to get the warnings in a separate output file ?